# How to realize such a bootstrap fixed-top navbar menu with background image and arrow down on active item

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using boostrap 4 and trying to realize such a navbar:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0l9kmeirf04x39e/navbar_desired.jpg

The navbar is fixed-bottom, and has to be fixed-top after scrolling down the viewports height. This works perfectly with this html code:

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-bottom" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="img/logo_small.png"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#a">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#b">Link 2</a>
            </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#c">Link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#d">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#e">Link 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Masthead -->
  <header id="home" class="masthead">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-xs-12 offset-xs-0 align-self-end">
          <div id="brand-fixed-masthead"><img src="img/logo_big.png"></div>
          <h1 class="text-white mt-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
          <p class="text-white text-uppercase font-weight-light mb-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

and this portion of jQuery:

```
  // Collapse Navbar
  var distance = $('#mainNav').offset().top;
  var navheight = $('#mainNav').outerHeight();
  var navbarCollapse = function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $('#mainNav').removeClass('fixed-bottom');
      $('#mainNav').addClass('fixed-top');
      $('#intro').addClass('masthead-fixed-top');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= distance) {
      $('#mainNav').removeClass('fixed-top');
      $('#mainNav').addClass('fixed-bottom');
      $('#intro').removeClass('masthead-fixed-top');
    }

  };

  // Collapse now if page is not at top
  navbarCollapse();

  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);
```

This is what I have right now:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8a5s5jlm3y4l37/navbar_now.jpg

But I have no clue how to bring in the backgrounded arrow down on the active link items.

Suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry you won't need any glue to do this.

use css :after to create the arrow

```
:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

and apply it with your active class to the clicked element.

https://codepen.io/carlos27/pen/WBqWPp

I added the jQuery as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the typo :-) and thank you very much for the code. But it brings not the desired result: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz9kdle7a4hzkqq/navbar_try1.JPG).

The problem is, the arrow doesn't changes his position, even the active link has changed and also the arrow will not show the background image of the masthead. 

Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. Therefore I attached the link to the desired result. As I said, the arrow has to show the background image of the masthead, as an "extension" of the masthead. I guess, some jQuery is necessary, pure css will not help.

Comment: @ViktorTöws I just updated my answer with an example

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. Your example looks great, but it is still not the desired result. In your example the arrow has the same transparent background color as the navbar. Thats fine and works, but my real problem is, that I have a background image which starts in the masthead and is also part of the arrow as I mentioned in my question and showed in this link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0l9kmeirf04x39e/navbar_desired.jpg